# import Azure Devops pipeline variables from json file

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I want to use json file to store variables used by powershell script. In azure devops I have configured pipeline, pipeline contains powershell script with a list of variables in it. I would like to use json file and store in this file all variables. I want to store json file in Azure repo, and use it once pipeline is started. I dont want to use variable groups. I found this solution [**Json to Variable**]https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OneLuckiDev.json2variable&targetId=02fbae5c-cc01-4c8b-a90f-7393a3156347 but I read some uncomplimentary opinions about this task. Is there any method to use json file as a place to store variables, or maybe I can use different file format?
UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: What the issue with this extension? try it and after that ask.

Comment: Why not just read the json file with powershell? If you want to set these as environment variables that are used in later steps in your pipeline then `echo` the variables like so: `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=a]20"` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-in-script

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not directly to use the Powershell built-in cmdlet: `ConvertFrom-Json`. See this official doc about this cmdlet description: [Powershell: ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6).

You can add the script:

```
Get-Content "{JSON file path}" | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json
```

`Get-Content` would read the JSON file into an array of strings, and `ConvertFrom-Json` convert these strings into the PSCustomObject object. Then you can call the exactly object with simple leverage dot notation(`.`), then use it with this format into the task script.

Here is the simple sample can for you refer:

```
$data = Get-content {your JSON file path}| out-string | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output $data.ts
```

[image]

Here I tried in my local Powershell-ISE which is same usage in Powershell task. *`ts` is one of my JSON object. In azure devops, you can use the path like `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\..\..\...json` to specified your file location if you store it in Repos.*

Comment: Hi, That is what I am exactly looking for, I have tested this using pipeline inline script and it works fine. Thank You!!

Comment: one more question, why I am still getting error with message "Get-Content : Cannot find path 'D:\Variables.json' because it does not exist.". I tested this solution using pipeline inline script and it worked. Now in my powershell script I am using this -->  `$JsonFilePath = "$($Build.SourcesDirectory)\Variables.json"
$JsonDataBase = Get-Content $($JsonFilePath) | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json` and facing errors, file is stored in devops repo.

Comment: @tester81. According to your script configuration, I assume your `Variable.json` in located in the root path of your repos, right? Change your path script as `$JsonFilePath = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Variables.json" 
$JsonDataBase = Get-Content $JsonFilePath | out-string | ConvertFrom-Json`. The method you used does not correct, because the correct path value should be `d:\a\1\s\...` instead of `D:\....`.

Comment: OK, I ve just corrected, now I have `$JsonFilePath = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Variables.json"`, but still there is something wrong, now got an error like --> `D:\a\1\s\Get-RbacReport.ps1 : The term 'Build.SourcesDirectory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.`

Comment: @tester81. This is the simple sample on my powershell: https://imgur.com/a/Rc0SVsW .If convenient, could you show me how's your script like?

Comment: I have the same code as Yours, pls have a look at UPDATE in problem description at the beginning.

Comment: @tester81. No problem about that script. As I see, in your error message, the unrecognized error caused from the `Get-RbacReport.ps1` file. Does it is the one you defined? For troubleshoting, please just define the variable `$JsonFilePath` when write-host its value, to see whether the path value can be got successfully.

Comment: I have used env variable inside the script --> `$RepoPath = $Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` and it resolved the problem.