# Azure Pipeline: Read values from json file in the repo and store it in pipeline variable (without powershell)

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I have an azure repo that triggers an azure pipeline on every commit to any branch.

on this repo there is a json file `file.json`.
With sample content:

```
{
 "key1": "value1",
 "key2": "value2" 
}
```

how can i read values from this json file in the pipeline and store them in pipeline variables? (I want to avoid powershell)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import Azure Devops pipeline variables from json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597755/import-azure-devops-pipeline-variables-from-json-file)

Comment: @VinceBowdren Thanks for the hint. I saw that too, I should have mentioned that I'm looking for a solution without powershell....

Comment: That's a crucial limitation; you'd best Edit the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution. First you create a bash action with the following syntax:

```
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=varName;]$(jq .key1 file.json)"
  name: setVarFromJsonFileValue
```

With `jq .key1 file.json` you can read the value of `key1`.

`jq` is a cli tool what seems to be preinstalled at the pipeline agent (i used ubuntu image).

Now `value1` is stored in the pipeline variable `varName` and you can access it in the whole job like this:

```
- script: |
    echo $(varName) 
  displayName: output value of var
```

The output is `value1`.

Comment: For me, the variable captured the quotes around the value. To prevent this, I had to add `-r` to the call to `jq`.